# Custom MAUI layout don't show any Control, but control have correct position and size,

Tags: .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

I custom a layout name ConstraintLayout according to AbsoluteLayout in MAUI.

It like AbsoluteLayout have a LayoutManager class,i overrride Measure and ArrangeChildren method in this class.

It also have a ConstrainLayout class.
`public class ConstraintLayout : Layout, IConstraintLayout`

Source Code at  [ConstraintLayout.Maui](https://github.com/xtuzy/SharpConstraintLayout/blob/Modify/SharpConstraintLayout.Maui/Widget/ConstraintLayout.Maui.cs)

I print control information, found control in layout have correct position and size, such as position of Entry at center of window. but nothing show at window.

I need set something at builder or Handler? i don't find doc about it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
I have try use AbsoluteLayout as base class, it show control, but not well. It will measure many times, that will waste many cpu time, and AbsoluteLayout store layout information, but my ConstraintLayout have store layout information, that will waste memory. So i want just use Layout as base class, i search maui source code, don't find handler belong to AbsoluteLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that `AbsoluteLayout` works via a `LayoutManager`.

Find `AbsoluteLayout.cs`. See its:

```cs
    protected override ILayoutManager CreateLayoutManager()
```

Do similar, but find `AbsoluteLayoutManager.cs`, and make a similar `ConstraintLayoutManager` that uses your constraint logic. Then your method in `ConstraintLayout` will be:

```cs
protected override ILayoutManager CreateLayoutManager()
{
    return new ConstraintLayoutManager(this);
}
```

---

NOTE: Don't do my (now deleted) comment's `ConstraintLayout : AbsoluteLayout ...`. Go back to your original `ConstraintLayout : Layout, IConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Thank you, finally i found i just use uncorrected Arrange method, View inherit form VisualElement and IView, they all have a Arrange method, i use it of VisualElement, so all control not show.